# Tokenization which works with terms that contain whitespace in Python?

Tags: python, regex, whitespace, tokenize

My standard approach to tokenize a text using a regex in Python is this:

```
> text = "Los Angeles is in California"
> tokens = re.findall(r'\w+', text)
> tokens
['Los','Angeles','is','in','California']
```

A problem arises if I want to find the name `Los Angeles` in the above text.

**What is the best way to find a needle which contains whitespace in a haystack?**

I am asking a general question, because the solution should also work for a case like `United States of America` and for needles which don't contain whitespace.

For example a simple `if "Los Angeles" in text` (match) would not do, because `if "for" in text` would also return a match. But I am looking for full words only (match `for` and not `California`).

Comment: First, you need to decide if "Los Angeles" is one token or two. Your text contains the string "Los Angeles", but your token stream has two separate tokens "Los" and "Angeles".

Comment: How is it that `Los Angeles` is a full word whereas `is in` is two separate ones? Is it because, `A` is capital in `Angeles`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple:

```
re.search(r'\b'+needle+r'\b', haystack)
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use a text parser like [`NLTK`](http://www.nltk.org/) for such tasks.

But for this case you can use following regex :

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b([A-Z]\w+ [A-Z]\w+)|(\w+)\b',text)
[('Los Angeles', ''), ('', 'is'), ('', 'in'), ('', 'California')]
```

the regex `r'([A-Z]\w+ [A-Z]\w+)|(\w+)'` will match 2 group the first is a pair word that its elements contain capital words! and the second will match a word!

Comment: This would not work with `United States of America`?

Comment: @boadescriptor Indeed and as there are a lot of possibilities for such problem i saied this answer is for this case!

Comment: Is there another way to search for a string in a string in Python which treats the string boundaries as word boundaries? I mean a `for "Los Angeles" in text` which considers the needle string a word.

Comment: @boadescriptor No, but whats wrong with `in` operation?